# Strichartz A Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

Are there any solution manuals for Robert Strichartz's *A Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms*? I've been looking everywhere, however, I can only find scattered solutions which aren't too reliable or consistent. It came highly recommended, but the solutions are basically non-existent and can't seem to find any supporting resources despite it being widely used.